# Greenplum DB stuck in recovery mode

Tags: recovery, greenplum

I have a Greenplum deployment with several segments.

version: postgres (Greenplum Database) 8.2.15

A few days ago after an error as seen from pg_log (below)

```
FATAL  54000   out of on_shmem_exit slots                                       
WARNING          1000      StartTransaction while in START state                                    
PANIC  XX000   Waiting on lock already held! (lwlock.c:557)                                        
LOG      0             server process (PID 224596) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted                                              
LOG      0             terminating any other active server processes                                   
FATAL  57P01   terminating connection due to administrator command                                
LOG      0             sweeper process (PID 102635) exited with exit code 2                                     
LOG      0             seqserver process (PID 102632) exited with exit code 2                                  
FATAL  57P03   the database system is in recovery mode                                             
LOG      0             ftsprobe process (PID 102633) exited with exit code 2                                     
FATAL  57P03   the database system is in recovery mode                                             
FATAL  57P03   the database system is in recovery mode                                             
FATAL  57P03   the database system is in recovery mode                                             
FATAL  57P03   the database system is in recovery mode                                             
FATAL  57P03   the database system is in recovery mode
```

For 4 days now database remains in recovery mode, gpstart, gpstop all return with errors "the database system is in recovery mode" afterwards fails.

See ps response below:

```
[gpadmin@mdw1 ~]$ ps -ef | grep post
gpadmin  2979 189094 0 12:25 pts/0  00:00:00 grep post
postfix  3264  3251 0 2015 ?    00:34:40 qmgr -l -t fifo -u
gpadmin 102637 230099 0 May18 ?    00:01:47 postgres: port 5432, stats sender process                                     
gpadmin 230099   1 0 Apr24 ?    02:47:53 /usr/local/greenplum-db-4.3.10.0/bin/postgres -D /data/master/gpseg-1 -p 5432 -b 1 -z 96 --silent-mode=true -i -M master -C -1 -x 194 -E
gpadmin 230100 230099 0 Apr24 ?    00:49:45 postgres: port 5432, master logger process                                     
[gpadmin@mdw1 ~]$
```

I have searched a lot but am not able to find as a solution kindly assist with pointers on how to bring the database up.

Comment: You are on version 4.3.10 which is very old.  It is actually even out of technical guidance.  You should try opening a support ticket with Pivotal and then after this is fixed, upgrade to a supported version.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response, yes I know its quite old, I was hoping to get some help on this out here, hoping someone may have had this issue